# How manual add MSVC 2010 compiler as tool chain?

Tags: visual-c++, qt4, qt-creator

As the title, I have a "portable" version of MSVC 2010 (included vcvars32.bat, .., and already tested for working). How can i make qt creator "auto detect" or any ways to add to tools chain list manual?

Comment: I have readed Qt Creator source and got the solution at `msvctoolchain.cpp` file ;)